# Create dependency files in Makefile

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I am using a Makefile including  a rule to create a dependency file. The compiler is GCC.

```
%.d: %.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -M $< | \
    sed 's,\($(notdir $*)\.o\) *:,$(dir $@)\1 $@: ,' > $@.tmp
    mv $@.tmp $@
```

I am quite new in Makefile technique and I find it a little bit difficult to understand this rule composed of a mixture of several options.
Can somebody give a simple explanation how this rule works?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%.d: %.c`

All files ending in `.d` can be made using this rule, as long as there is a `.c` file with the same directory and stem relative to the current directory or one of the vpaths.

`mkdir -p $(@D)`

Create the topmost and all intermediate directories for `$(@D)`, which is an automatic make variable that expands to the directory part of the current target.

`$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -M $< | \`

Invoke the C compiler on the first prerequisite (`whatever.c`) and tell it to output a list of make dependencies to the standard output. Pipe this output to

`sed 's,\($(notdir $*)\.o\) *:,$(dir $@)\1 $@: ,' > $@.tmp`

sed. The rules in the output will have the same path as the source files, but whoever wrote this rule wants the objects files in a different directory so we need sed to substitute the paths.

Sed captures any rules with targets ending with `.o` that match `$(notdir $*)`. `$*` is another automatic variable that expands to the pattern that matches `%` in the current rule, and `notdir` will strip any directory parts so you're left with the filename stem with no extension.

Sed then prepends `$(dir $@)` to the object file target, which is the same thing as `$(@D)` we saw above, and adds the dependency file itself (`$@`) as a target of the same prerequisites. This output is redirected to a file with the name of the current target + `.tmp`.

`mv $@.tmp $@`

Moves the previous file to the real target of the rule.

---

Side note: if you don't mind the dependency files being generated in the same directory as the object files then these recipes are outdated, you can achieve the same thing with something like:

```
sources := src/somefile1.c src/somefile2.c
objects := $(sources:src/%.c=obj/%.o)
deps    := $(objects:.o=.d)

CFLAGS := -MMD -MP

.PHONY: all
all $(objects)

$(objects): obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

-include $(deps)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks you!